# emacs as python IDE with elpy and django

Tags: python, django, emacs, elpy

I have my emacs configured with elpy and it works very fine: Syntaxis correction, autocomplete, see documentation, go to definition etc.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with django classes. Is there any way to enable the use of django in my emacs ?

Comment: What does not work ? How did you configure elpy and what did you try to fix that ?

Comment: For example, got to definition works with my defined functions, but not with django functions. I have not configured elpy... I supose that I have to configure it to use it with django, but I don't know how? This is my problem.